# How to make pycharm's auto completion work in class definitions for typed attributes?

Tags: python, object, pycharm, typing

when I set the type for an object in the init statement, the auto completion works in the init statement:

[Type definition and auto completion in init function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmQl0.png)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel

class TestAutoComplete:

    def __init__(self):
        self.testLabel: QLabel
        self.testLabel.
```

Then when I want to auto complete the same variable in another function, it is not working:

[Auto Completion not working in other functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOtPH.png)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel

class TestAutoComplete:

    def __init__(self):
        self.testLabel: QLabel

    def otherFunction(self):
        self.testLabel.
```

How can I set the type for an attribute once and then have autocompletion in every of the classes function definitions?

Kind regards
Bastian

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be reminded to include a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question when such is applicable. Don't include code only as an image, consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I have found the answer by accident. You have to type a class variable:

[Auto-completion in functions working with a type on a class variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdjO7.png)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel

class TestAutoComplete:
    testLabel: QLabel

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def otherFunction(self):
        self.testLabel.
```

This seems odd to me. I am a python beginner, but I thought to have understood that the testLabel in this screenshot is a class variable and accessible only via TestAutoComplete.testLabel and not via self.testLabel. May this be a bug in the pycharm auto completion?

Comment: In that case you have 2 variables with the same name, one instance variable and another class variable. When you initialize the variable in `__init__` it becomes an instance variable but the class variable isn't changed. (Test it by attributing different values to the 2 variables - preferably using a simpler type). Since both variables are type hinted with the same type the auto-completion suggestions will of course be the same.

Comment: Hi! As you can see in the example above in the actual question a type hint in the __init__ statement does not make the auto-completion work in a function definition. Only the type hint of class variable seems to make it work. So it should be a bug.

Comment: As I previously said, your example does not include the text as code. It's expected of an OP to provide an example that can be copy-pasted to save readers and answerers that part of the work. I would also advise that the example be written using standard library classes, because otherwise you're expecting readers to install PyQT which a lot of people don't use.

Comment: Added the code snippets in the text. The example can be tried with any other imported class, does not need to be PyQT